# How to convert class to inherited class while using ActiveRecord

Tags: inheritance, activerecord, asp.net-mvc-2, castle-activerecord

I've got a class `Project` and a class `Case`, which inherits from `Project`. 
When having a list of `Projects` we might decide later on to make a `Case` of the selected `Project`. How can I achieve this?

Project:

```
[ActiveRecord (Table = "projects", Lazy = true), JoinedBase]
public class Project : ActiveRecordValidationBase<Project>
{
        private int _id;
        [PrimaryKey(PrimaryKeyType.Identity, "id")]
        public virtual int Id
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set { _id = value; }
        }
}
```

Case:

```
 [ActiveRecord(Table = "cases", Lazy = true)]
    public class Case : Project
    {
        private int _caseId;
        [JoinedKey("case_id")]
        public virtual int CaseId
        {
            get { return _caseId; }
            set { _caseId = value; }
        }
    }
```

I hope my subject and problem are clear :)

Answer (score 1):

See [NHibernate - Changing sub-types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478296/nhibernate-changing-sub-types), 
it talks about discriminators, but in principle the answer is the same: either avoid this situation by refactoring, or hack around it with raw SQL.